# Pass an unescaped resource bundle property to a JSF component attribute

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, internationalization

More specific, i need to pass some **i18n** message (using a *resource bundle*) to a *inputText* **placeholder** (using **JSF2.2** `p:passthrough`):

**Properties File:**

```
someI18nMessage=<helloWorld>
```

**XHTML**:

```
<h:inputText id="someInput" value="#{someController.someInput}" p:placeholder="#{i18n[someI18nMessage]}" />
```

This prints an **escaped** `<helloWorld>` to the webpage.

The usual way of **unescape** resource bundle messages is via:

```
<h:outputText value="#{i18n[someI18nMessage]}" escape="false" />
```

but i can't inline this component inside de `p:placeholder` attribute of `h:inputText`.

Comment: As the passthrough-attributes will not be processed by the JSF-runtime I think there is only the workaround to escape on your own: `#{unescapeBean.i18n('someI18nMessage')}`.

Comment: Its there a way to configure outside the xhtml all or certain resource bundle to be not escaped?

Comment: I don't think there is one. The escaping is done on rendering the HTML, not on getting the value from the Bundle. JSF is doing this implicitly so my first idea with escaping yourself was wrong and won't work. 
You could overwrite the default JSF-Renderers but I would not do this therefor. Could you give me a concrete example where unescaped HTML in a placeholder is really necessary?

Comment: My actual example is using html entities to represent an accent, like for example "fo&oacute;" or a letter with a tilde "ba&ntilde;

Comment: OK. This is working if you unescape yourself. The tilde won't be escaped by [ResponseWriter.writeText](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.2/javadocs/javax/faces/context/ResponseWriter.html#writeText%28java.lang.Object,%20javax.faces.component.UIComponent,%20java.lang.String%29), the `<` will be escaped.

Comment: The idea of encoding the tilde and accents to HTML entities, is to have full compatibility. For the < the idea is to allow strong and em tags to i18n messages. I guess the only solution is to not encode tildes and accents, and to use outputText with encode=false for messages with strong and em, but i dont like the idea of havings two ways for rendering i18n messages.